Add custom domain on Clouflare Worker&Pages
When using Cloudflare Workers&Pages, why do I have to explicitly add a custom domain through the Workers&Pages menu instead of just adding a CNAME record that points to the Workers&Pages instance?
From my understanding of how CNAME records work, it should be sufficient to add a record pointing to the hostname of the w&p instance.
When I try this way I get a 522 error connection timed out, specifying that the server didn't respond.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
